# Consecutive values?

Tags: python, function

Learning python, but having trouble telling function to find consecutive locations with same values. When I run the code, there's no errors but gives out the incorrect output. Suggestions on what to change?

```
def same_values(xs):
    same = False
    for i in (xs):
        if xs == xs[1:]:
            same = True
    else:
        return same
same_values('Misses') # This should return as true
```

Comment: Please explain what your code is supposed to do. What input should it take?

Comment: Also, are the comparisons case sensitive? Of course this will always return `False` though, `xs == xs[1:]` is never `True`.

Comment: It should take integers such as [1,2,3,3,5] as true. It doesn't need to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are looking for a consecutive pair in the list and returning true if you find one.

```
def same_values(xs):
    for i in range(len(xs)-1):
        if xs[i] == xs[i+1]:
            return True
    return False

>>> same_values('misses')
True
>>> same_values('mises')
False
```

Would give you the correct answer.
However python has a powerful iterator algebra. The advantage of this is that it would work with iterators (iterators don't generally support `len()`) as well as lists:

```
import itertools as it

def same_values(xs):
    a, b = it.tee(xs)
    next(b, None)
    return any(x == y for x, y in zip(a, b))
```

This pattern is described in the `itertools` recipes as [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html?highlight=pairwise):

```
import itertools as it

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = it.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def same_values(xs):
    return any(x == y for x, y in pairwise(xs))
```

For example to check if any 2 consecutive lines in a file are the same (this wouldn't work with the `list` version):

```
with open('somefile') as f:
    print(same_values(f))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Didn't know about an iterator.